# Is it possible to have all elements in div justified even if they are larger than div?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have multiple divs in another div

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="div1">text1</div>
  <div id="div2">text2</div>
  <div id="div3">another text</div>
  ...
  <div id="divN">text N</div>
</div>
```

Each inner div has not set width property, but it has `display: inline-block` so each div suits to its content (text). If I leave them like this inner divs fill horizontally browser until they meet end of line and they begin from the left side. It is fine for me. But unfortunately each "line" of divs ends up in a different distance from right side. I'd like to justify them like i can justify a text. I tried `display: flex` and `justify-content: space-around` css methods, but they put all inner divs in one line so the part of them is outside the screen. Is there a way to achieve my goal? Pure css would be the best solution.

Comment: `text-align: justify`? `flex-wrap:wrap`?

Comment: i dont want to align text. i want to justify inner divs in container

Comment: `text-align` sets the alignment of inline-level content of a block container. inline-blocks are inline-level content.

Comment: flex-wrap with display: flex and justify-content made my goal. Thank you for advice

Answer (score 0):

If you use inline-block elements, you can set their alignment with [`text-align`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#text-align):

> This property describes how the inline-level content of a block is
>   aligned along the inline axis if the content does not completely fill
>   the line box.

Note the last line behaves differently, if you want to justify it too you should also use [`text-align-last`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#text-align-last):

> This property describes how the last line of a block or a line right
>   before a forced line break is aligned when ‘text-align’ is ‘justify’.

```css
text-align: justify;
text-align-last: justify;
```

```css
.container {
  text-align: justify;
  -moz-text-align-last: justify;
  text-align-last: justify;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 500px;
}
.item {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">text1</div>
  <div class="item">text2</div>
  <div class="item">text3</div>
  <div class="item">text4</div>
  <div class="item">text5</div>
  <div class="item">text6</div>
</div>
```

---

If you use flexbox, this will no longer apply. However, you can set [`justify-content`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#propdef-justify-content) to `space-around` or `space-between` to justify.

> The justify-content property aligns flex items along the main axis of
>   the current line of the flex container.

Note that, by default, flexbox containers are [single-line](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#single_line). If you want to make them [multi-line](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#multi_line), use the [`flex-wrap`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-wrap-property) property:

> The flex-wrap property controls whether the flex container is
>   single-line or multi-line

```css
justify-content: space-around;
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

```css
.container {
  text-align: justify;
  -moz-text-align-last: justify;
  text-align-last: justify;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.item {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">text1</div>
  <div class="item">text2</div>
  <div class="item">text3</div>
  <div class="item">text4</div>
  <div class="item">text5</div>
  <div class="item">text6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, examples with

> text-align & inline-block
>
> justify-content & flex , wrap

```css
/* inline-block (childs ) */
.container {
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:justify;
  vertical-align:top;
  background:tomato;
  font-size:0;/*for last pseudo line to use no space optionnal */
}
.container:after, body:after {
  content:'';
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
  vertical-align:top;/* remove gap underneath*/
}
/* flex (parent */
.container2 {
  display:inline-flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content:space-between;
  background:turquoise;
}
/* both */
body>div {
  width:200px;
  padding:3px;
  border:solid;
}
div div {
  font-size:1rem;/* if font-size parent was set to 0 */
  display:inline-block;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.2)/* lets see them a bit*/;
}
div div:first-child {/* or any elements that needs to span a line */
  color:white;
  font-weight:bold;
  background:none;
  width:100%;/* 100% = full line */
  text-align:center;
  }
/* snippet */
body {
  margin:50px;
  text-align:justify;
  }
kbd {
  color:brown
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div  >INLINE-BLOCK <kbd>IE8</kbd></div>
  <div  >text1</div>
  <div  >text2</div>
  <div  >another text</div>
  <div  >text N</div>
  <div  >text1</div>
  <div  >text2</div>
  <div >another text</div>
  <div  >another text</div>
  <div  >text N</div>
  <div >text N</div>
  <div  >text1</div>
  <div  >text2</div>
  <div  >another text</div>
  <div  >text N</div>
  <div  >another text</div>
  <div  >text N</div>
  <div  >text1</div>
</div>
<div class="container2">
  <div  >INLINE-FLEX <kbd>IE11</kbd></div>
  <div  >text1</div>
  <div  >text2</div>
  <div  >another text</div>
  <div  >text N</div>
  <div  >text1</div>
  <div  >text2</div>
  <div >another text</div>
  <div  >another text</div>
  <div  >text N</div>
  <div >text N</div>
  <div  >text1</div>
  <div  >text2</div>
  <div  >another text</div>
  <div  >text N</div>
  <div  >another text</div>
  <div  >text N</div>
  <div  >text1</div>
</div>
```